# htaccess - multiple rewrites & capture groups

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to handle multiple areas of an application, but the URLs are not being rewrited as expected.

This is the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^division/(.*)/section/(.*)$ ./index.php?division=$1&section=$2
RewriteRule ^division/(.*)$ ./index.php?division=$1
RewriteRule ^area/(.*)$ ./index.php?area=$1
```

**What's expected:**

1. **If the URI matches** `division/some_division/section/some_section` rewrite to `index.php?division=some_division&section=some_section`
2. If **no** section (`section/some_section`) is defined, go to the second rule -

   **If the URI matches** `division/some_division` rewrite only to `index.php?division=some_division`
3. If **no** division is defined, and **the URI matches** `area/some_area` rewrite to `index.php?area=some_area`

I'm almost sure I can combine the two first rules, I've tried this regex but it didn't work:

`^division/(.*)( /section/(.*) )?$`

It supposed to make `/section/some_section` an **optional** value.

Unfortunately nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^division/(.*)/section/(.*)$ ./index.php?division=$1&section=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^division/(.*)$              ./index.php?division=$1            [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^area/(.*)$                  ./index.php?area=$1                [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The .htaccess file is inside a subdirectory. `RewriteBase /` will not work, and also `/?`. So all you changed is `[QSA,L]` and it didn't change anything.

Comment: I didn't think that I have to inform that it's a subdirectory, sorry. Also, your answer contains `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}`. Maybe you forgot something?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. It's hard to see

Comment: I see, my bad. Unfortunately, it still didn't change the final result.

Comment: Found something interesting - when I type `division/123/section/123`, the rewrite applies correctly, but all the css, images, and js are being searched in `division/123/section/123/style.css` (example) too. Is there a way to stop it? (found in access & error log)

Comment: Found the solution. Your answer is not the solution but you helped me. Get a +1. Thanks